# Compare multidimensional arrays for different entries and storing them

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to teach myself how multidimensional arrays work and how I can compare and manipulate them in php I have created two arrays with the same scheme but with one different value in each.

first array

```
      $datastuff1 = array( array(  Ttitle => "rose", 
                            Price => 1.25,
                            Number => 15 
                            ),
                     array( Ttitle => "daisy", 
                            Price => 0.75,
                            Number => 25
                           ),
                     array( Ttitle => "lilly", 
                            Price => 1.75,
                            Number => 3
                           ),
                     array( Ttitle => "orchid", 
                            Price => 1.15,
                            Number => 7 
                        )
                     );
```

second array

```
     $datastuff2 = array( array(  Title => "rose", 
                            Price => 1.25,
                            Number => 15 
                            ),
                     array( Title => "daisy", 
                            Price => 0.75,
                            Number => 25
                           ),
                     array( Title => "nettle", 
                            Price => 2.75,
                            Number => 33
                           ),

                     array( Title => "orchid", 
                            Price => 1.15,
                            Number => 7 
                        )
                     );
```

I now want to loop through both arrays and `foreach` item that matches (using the title as a key) in both arrays add to a new matching array and for each item that doesn't match in both arrays add to my not matching array

heres my code

```
    $matchingarray = array();
    $notmatchingarray = array();

    foreach($datastuff1 as $data1){
        foreach($datastuff2 as $data2){
           if($data2['Title']== $data1['Ttitle'])
           {
              $matchingarray[] = $data1;
           }
        else {
        $notmatchingarray[] = $data1;
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I output the contents of the arrays using

```
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($notmatchingarray);
   echo "</pre>";
```

I get the output

```
    Array
    (
     [0] => Array
     (
        [Ttitle] => rose
        [Price] => 1.25
        [Number] => 15
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => rose
        [Price] => 1.25
        [Number] => 15
    )

   [2] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => rose
        [Price] => 1.25
        [Number] => 15
    )

   [3] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => daisy
        [Price] => 0.75
        [Number] => 25
    )

  [4] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => daisy
        [Price] => 0.75
        [Number] => 25
    )

   [5] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => daisy
        [Price] => 0.75
        [Number] => 25
    )

  [6] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => lilly
        [Price] => 1.75
        [Number] => 3
    )

  [7] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => lilly
        [Price] => 1.75
        [Number] => 3
    )

  [8] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => lilly
        [Price] => 1.75
        [Number] => 3
    )

  [9] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => lilly
        [Price] => 1.75
        [Number] => 3
    )

  [10] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => orchid
        [Price] => 1.15
        [Number] => 7
    )

  [11] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => orchid
        [Price] => 1.15
        [Number] => 7
    )

  [12] => Array
    (
        [Ttitle] => orchid
        [Price] => 1.15
        [Number] => 7
    )

    )
```

so to me it seems as though its looping round three times (the amount of items that match) and each time putting the matching items in the array.

What I want is all the items that DON'T match (using the Title as a key) in the non-matching array and the ones that DO in the matching array. I'm missing something painstakingly obvious I suppose.

Any help would be grand
regard mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't simply copy/paste your array definitions so I didn't test, but you need to check for equality and if found then `break` out of the inner loop.  Also, after the inner loop, check if it was added to `$matchingarray` and if not, add to `$notmatchingarray`:

```
foreach($datastuff1 as $key => $data1){
    foreach($datastuff2 as $data2){
        //match add to $matchingarray
        if($data2['Title'] == $data1['Ttitle']) {
            $matchingarray[$key] = $data1; //use $key so we can check later
            break; //we have a match so why keep looping?
        }
    }
    //if no match add to $notmatchingarray
    if(!isset($matchingarray[$key])) { //we used $key so we can check for it
        $notmatchingarray[$key] = $data1; //don't need $key here but oh well
    }
}
```

Alternate way that may be easier to follow:

```
foreach($datastuff1 as $key => $data1){
    $match = false; //no match

    foreach($datastuff2 as $data2) {
        //match add to $matchingarray
        if($data2['Title'] == $data1['Ttitle']) {
            $matchingarray[] = $data1;
            $match = true; //match
            break; //we have a match so why keep looping?
        }
    }
    //if no match add to $notmatchingarray
    if(!$match) {
        $notmatchingarray[] = $data1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response they both work and i understand the code to a cetain extent, but i was just wondering is there a reason why i might want to keep the key as in the first one or simply create a new index as in the second example

Comment: @Mike: In the first example I use the `$key` so that I can refer to it and check for it in the `if` later.  I couldn't use `[]` because that could be 0 or 100 etc... and I couldn't check for it later because I wouldn't know what it was.  In the second example that is not important because I set the `$match` = `true` or `false` and I can check that.

Comment: @Mike: Also, in the second example, if you remove the `break` then it allows for multiples matches (more than one matching `Title` in either array)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have been fiddling with the code to better understand it. Really appreciate your responses.